# Non-template ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following IVP: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^3}{e^{2x} + y^2}$ with $x(1) = 0$.
My progress: Indeed, there is no progress in this problem since I applied all famous methods, but none of them leads to solution. Pretty sure some creative idea or substitution kills the problem, I am just too weak to find that. Any help will be strongly welcomed!

Comment: $x(1) = 0$ means that $y=1$ and $x=0$. It is just another style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^3}{e^{2x} + y^2}$$
$$\frac{dy}{de^{2x}}\frac{de^{2x}}{dx}  = \frac{y^3}{e^{2x} + y^2}$$
$$2e^{2x}\frac{dy}{de^{2x}}  = \frac{y^3}{e^{2x} + y^2}$$
Substitute $u=e^{2x}$:
$$2u\frac{dy}{du}  = \frac{y^3}{u + y^2}$$
$$2u(u+y^2) = {y^3}\frac{du}{dy} $$
This is Bernoulli's equation:
$$y^2u'-2yu=2\dfrac {u^2}{y}$$ 
$$\left (\dfrac {u}{y^2} \right )'=2\dfrac {u^2}{y^5}$$ 
$$\dfrac {y^4}{u^2}\left (\dfrac {u}{y^2} \right )'=\dfrac 2y$$ 
$$\dfrac {y^4}{u^2}d\left (\dfrac {u}{y^2} \right )=2\dfrac {dy}y$$
Integrate both sides. You can easily finish.

Comment: Very creative and awesome solution. I have used substitutions such as $\frac{e^{x}}{y}$ but using $e^{2x}$ turned out to be indeed much useful. Yeah, after Bernoulli is easy.

Comment: Hi thanks @DarkKnight Yes I guess it's more simple. It's easy to solve now. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{ydy}{dx} = \frac{y^4}{e^{2x} + y^2}$$
First, we obsere that changing $y$ into $-y$ doesn't change the equation. This draw us to change of function :
$$Y=y^2\quad\implies\quad \frac{ydy}{dx}=\frac12 \frac{dY}{dx}$$
$$\frac12 \frac{dY}{dx}=\frac{Y^2}{e^{2x} + Y}$$
In order to avoid exponential in the ODE obviously we change of variable :
$$X=e^{2x}\quad\implies\quad dx=\frac{dX}{2X}$$
$$X\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{Y^2}{X + Y}$$
$$\frac{dX}{dY}=\frac{X^2}{Y^2}+\frac{X}{Y}$$
We observe that this is an homogenous ODE. The usual transformation in such a case is :
$$u=\frac{X}{Y}\quad\implies\quad X=Yu\quad\implies\quad \frac{dX}{dY}=u+Y\frac{du}{dY}$$
$$u+Y\frac{du}{dY}=u^2+u$$
$$\frac{dY}{Y}=\frac{du}{u^2}\quad\implies\quad \ln|Y|=-\frac{1}{u}+c=-\frac{Y}{X}+c$$
Condition $x=0$ at $y=1\quad\implies\quad X=e^{2*0}=1\quad$ at $\quad Y=1^2=1$

$\ln|1|=-\frac{1}{1}+c=0\quad\implies\quad c=1 \quad\implies\quad \ln|Y|=-\frac{Y}{X}+1$

Thus the solution on the form of implicit equation is :
$$\boxed{\ln(y^2)+\frac{y^2}{e^{2x}}=1}$$

The explicit solution $y(x)$ cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. Solving the above implicit equation for $y$ requires a special function, namely the Lambert W function :
$$y(x)=\pm e^x\:\sqrt{W\big(e^{1-2x}\big)}$$
$W\big(e^{1-2x}\big)$ is positive for all real $x$.